# Auto-resize images with jQuery to fit container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I'm trying to build a script that browser-resizes images that are larger than the container:

```
  $('img').each(function(i){
    var parent_width = parseInt($(this).parent().width()),
        image_width = parseInt($(this).width());

    if(parent_width !== image_width){
      $(this).width(parent_width).wrap(
         '<a class="resized-image" href="' + this.src + '">'
       + ' <span class="msg">'
       + '   This image has been resized to ' + parent_width + ' pixels'
       + '   and ' + $(this).height() + ' pixels'
       + '</span>'
       + '</a>'
      );
    }
  });
```

The resizing works, but how can I get a nice message there telling the user the original image size, percentage to which the image was resized and the original image size in KB?

Like

> This image has been resized to 400 x 300 (50%). Original image has 800 x 600 and 75 KB. Click to view the original

So far I could only figure out the width of the resized image (the height() returns 0 for some reason)

Comment: The filesize is irrelevant and useless information. Unless a thumbnail script was used, the image has already been downloaded, so if I click to view the fullsize then it will just come from cache instantly.

Comment: yes, they both have the same file size because they are the same image, but still I'd like to display this information in the ribbon above the image...

Comment: There's an easy way to resize in CSS:
`img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }`

Of course, you don't get your clickable links that way.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3877027/901048) for tips about this problem. You can't measure the dimensions of an image until it's fully `.load`ed (that's why you're getting the `height()` as zero), but you can't detect when it's `.load`ed if it's cached without a little additional trickery.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code with $(window).load

```
$(window).load(function() {
     // your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('img').one('load', function () {

    var parent_width = parseInt($(this).parent().width()),
        image_width = parseInt($(this).width());

    if(parent_width !== image_width){
      $(this).width(parent_width).wrap(
         '<a class="resized-image" href="' + this.src + '">'
       + ' <span class="msg">'
       + '   This image has been resized to ' + parent_width + ' pixels'
       + '   and ' + $(this).height() + ' pixels'
       + '</span>'
       + '</a>'
      );
    } 

});

$('img').each(function () {
     //If image is cached by browsers, trigger .load()
    if (this.complete){        
         $(this).trigger('load');
    }
 });
​
```

Test in [jsfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/kibria/DgHRa/).